# Executing Related Commands into SSH from C#

Tags: c#, ssh

Im trying to execute consecutive commands on SSH from C# i have three commands subcommand1,subcommand2 and subcommand3.Despite successfully connecting to the destination server, i cant get results from the below through C#, this works when i run the commands on putty. My main goal is to download a file from an oracle server 140.X.XX.3 to a local lynux server on IP denoted as MYIPADDRESS below. What Am i not doing right?

```
'using System;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;   
namespace SFTP_SHH
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Connection information
            string user = "username";
            string pass = "password";
            string host = "MYIPADDRESS ";
            string gainAcces = "sftp -o IdentityFile=/export/home/oracle/.ssh/rsps_rsa user@140.XX.XX.X;";
            //Set up the SSH connection    
          SshClient sshclient = new SshClient(host, user, pass);
                sshclient.Connect();
            string subcommand1 = gainAcces;
            string subcommand2 = "cd download";
            string subcommand3 = "get 2020-07-22_RESPONSYS_CRM_OUTGOING_CALLS2.csv.zip";
            SshCommand sc1 = sshclient.CreateCommand(subcommand1 && subcommand2 && subcommand3);
            sc1.Execute();                        
        }
      }
    }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `;` to separate the commands into three,

```
SshCommand sc1 = sshclient.CreateCommand(subcommand1 + ";" + subcommand2  + ";" + subcommand3);
```

What you are doing is using the `&&` (AND) operator between the three strings... which doesnt quite work the way you are thinking. You can use the && operator as part of the three commands by adding it as a string ... not c# operator (might not work on all linux systems),

```
SshCommand sc1 = sshclient.CreateCommand(subcommand1 + "&&" + subcommand2  + "&&" + subcommand3);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,this doesn't work still just executes but the file is not copied